# Model objects are null in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven, servlets

I am using Spring Framkework 4.1.6.RELEASE.

I have a Rest Controller and an ordinary controller.
The ordinary controller adds an object to the model, but this object is not there in the jsp.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried two different methods:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/mymapping")

public class StatusController {

    private Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(StatusController.class); 

    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    public ModelAndView myMethod1(final HttpServletRequest aRequest, final HttpServletResponse aResponse) {

        ModelAndView tempMAV = new ModelAndView("myjsp");
        tempMAV.addObject("test","test");
        return tempMAV;
    }       

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value="2")
    public String method2(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("test","test");
        return "myjsp";
    }       
}
```

In method 1 the jsp is displayed but the variable "test" is not filled.

```
test: ${test}
```

With method 2 I get a 404, the jsp myjsp is not found because the path

```
http://localhost:{...mypath...}/mymapping/WEB-INF/jsp/myjsp.jsp
```

does not exist.

In my pom.xml I added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My servlet contains:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

My jsp starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" version="2.0">
<jsp:directive.page language="java"
    contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p> test: ${test}</p>
```

---

### edit

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

<display-name>My display name</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Expose request to current thread (required for session and request-scoping) -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/config/spring-mvc-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I change my servlet content to:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                <property name="viewClass"
                    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

then at least method 2 works again, which means it shows the jsp, but still the variable test is not filled.

Comment: Added it to the description of the problem. I couldn't post everything at once because stackoverflow wouldn't tell me in which line I didn't convert the code properly.

Comment: Can you post your web.xml?

Comment: thank you for adding the needed data, can you try with the code provided in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUISSOUMA Issam suggested to use UrlBasedViewResolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

This helped to make method2 work.

Additionally, I added the following code to my web.xml, which made the variables be filled:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What I still don't unterstand is why I need to add the JspServlet configuration to the web.xml in this specific case. In two other projects of ours I saw the same controller methods etc. without the declaration of JspServlet in web.xml and it does work without it.

Answer (score 0):

In your Config change the prefix to "/WEB-INF/jsp/":

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass"
value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

You shoud access to your controller before:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/mymapping")
public class StatusController {

    private Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(StatusController.class); 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/method1", method = GET)
    public ModelAndView myMethod1(final HttpServletRequest aRequest, final HttpServletResponse aResponse) {

        ModelAndView tempMAV = new ModelAndView("myjsp");
        tempMAV.addObject("test","test");
        return tempMAV;
    }       

    @RequestMapping(value = "/method2",method = GET)
    public String method2(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("test","test");
        return "myjsp";
    }       
}
```

To access to method1 Try with the following URL:

```
http://localhost:port/contextPath/mymapping/method1
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Now method1 also can't find the jsp anymore. It says: "HTTP Status 404 - /contextPath/mymapping/WEB-INF/jsp/myjsp.jsp"

Comment: The path where it tries to find the jsp is purely wrong. Yes, 404.

Comment: You should not access this way `/mymapping/WEB-INF/jsp/myjsp.jsp`

Comment: Well, it's not me who is trying that. The controller is doing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90907/discussion-between-guissouma-issam-and-nina).

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd Controller method, do it this way :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method2",method = GET)
    public String method2(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("test",new ObjectName());
        return "myjsp";
    }
```

You must understand that addAttribute is used for binding, so you can add Model classes and other stuff. Try it out.

Comment: Well, that's how I did it. I only returned a String, not an Object. Anyway, the object also does not appear in the jsp.